# Need to get HTML elements in React without using setTimeout

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am needing to grab dom elements in order to get heights and make calculations in the component. I need to grab them as soon as the page loads and my temporary solution was to use a setTimeout, and it works perfectly. The setTimeout was used to run 1 second after the page runs but i need a better way instead of the setTimeout, I've heard using useEffect would be good for this. This is my current code:

```
const OrderSummaryView = () => {
    const isMobile = useGetBreakpoint() === 'mobile'
    const { versionIsVariant } = useContext(Abtests.Context)
    const isFixedScrollEnabled = versionIsVariant('FIXED_SCROLL_ORDER_SUMMARY') && !isMobile

    const main = document.querySelector('main[class*="main"]')
    const cartItemsContainer = document.querySelector('#cartItems')
    const summaryContainer = document.querySelector('.summaryContainer')

    const [scrollPosition, setScrollPosition] = useState(0)
    const [itemContainerHeight, setItemContainerHeight] = useState(0)
    const [summaryContainerHeight, setsummaryContainerHeight] = useState(0)
    const [calculatedBreakpoint, setCalculatedBreakpoint] = useState(0)

    const handleScroll = () => {
        const position = window.pageYOffset
        setScrollPosition(position)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll, { passive: true })
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll)
        }
    }, [])

    setTimeout(() => {
        setItemContainerHeight(cartItemsContainer.clientHeight)
        if (summaryContainer.clientHeight !== 0) {
            setsummaryContainerHeight(summaryContainer.clientHeight)
        }
        setCalculatedBreakpoint(itemContainerHeight - summaryContainerHeight + 100)
    }, 2000)
    const mainHeight = main.clientHeight

    const isSticky = scrollPosition >= 90 && isFixedScrollEnabled && (scrollPosition < calculatedBreakpoint)
    const isPostSticky = (scrollPosition >= calculatedBreakpoint) && isFixedScrollEnabled

    const orderSummaryClassname = `orderSummary${isSticky ? `Div__is-sticky` : isPostSticky ? `Div__post-sticky` : 'Div'}`
    const postStickyTop = `${mainHeight - summaryContainerHeight - 50}px`

    return (
        <div className="summaryContainer">
            <div className={orderSummaryClassname}
                style={isPostSticky ? { top: postStickyTop } : isSticky ? { top: '10px' } : null}>
                <OrderSummaryTitle title="Order Summary" />
                <OrderSummaryBody isFixedScrollEnabled={isFixedScrollEnabled} />
                <DesignerCashback />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default OrderSummaryView
```

Answer (score 0):

`I've heard using useEffect would be good for this.`

Go check out the [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)